# Ruby/Rails Dependency Injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependency-injection

I am trying to learn about dependency injection in Ruby/Rails. How can I remove `Builder`s explicit reference to `Saw` using dependency injection?

```
class Builder
  attr_reader :saw

  def saw
    @saw ||= Saw.new(4)
  end

  def cut_wood
    Saw.saw
  end
end

class Saw
  attr_reader :blades

  def initialize(blades)
    @blades = blades
  end

  def saw
    # do something
  end
end
```

Comment: should be passed in initialize, consider creating a BuilderFactory

Comment: In Saw class you can use `attr_accessor :builders` now s = `Saw.new` `s.builders = "asdasdasd"` and also s.builders # to fet the set result so getter and setter complete for builders which is dependent an of saw

Comment: changed Builder#hammer to Builder#saw so it made more sense

Comment: yeah..... but dependencies are created through `attr_accessor` in spite of 10 lines code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move initialization of `Saw` to the default argument.

```
class Builder   
  def saw(saw = Saw.new(4))
    @saw = saw
  end

  def cut_wood
    Saw.saw
  end
end
```

`Builder#saw` supports dependency injection now.

Remember to remove `attr_reader :saw` from your code because it's being overridden by your custom reader.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Builder

  def initialize(saw=Saw.new(4))
    @saw = saw
  end

  def cut_wood
    @saw.saw
  end
end

# Use it
b = Builder.new
b.saw

another_saw = AnotherSaw.new
b = Builder.new(another_saw)
b.saw
```

You initialize the Builder instance by a default saw. So you can either use the default one or use your own. This way you decoupled Saw from Builder.

By the way, I don't know `hammer` is for so I didn't write it. It looks nothing more than an attr reader in your code.

Also I don't need the necessity of `attr_read :saw` so I removed it.